# Kinect communication problem

Tags: ros, communication, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have download the openni_kinect in my ROS Fuerte, and launched the OpenNI driver as follows:
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch(see http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch)

But it came across many communication error
Found 24 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/driver] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/register_depth_rgb] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/ir/rectify_ir] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric_rect] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_mono] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/rectify_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric_rect] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_nodelet_manager] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/rviz_1343258123122945215] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_color] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link1] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link3] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link2] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/points] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/debayer] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth_registered] raised an error:
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /camera/depth/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link1->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera/register_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link2->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/disparity_depth_registered->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/driver->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth_registered/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/ir/rectify_ir->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link1->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
- /rviz_1343258123122945215->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/rgb/rectify_color->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth/points->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link2->/rviz_1343258123122945215 (/tf)
- /camera/disparity_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link->/rviz_1343258123122945215 (/tf)
- /camera_base_link3->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link1->/rviz_1343258123122945215 (/tf)
- /camera_nodelet_manager->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/rgb/rectify_mono->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link3->/rviz_1343258123122945215 (/tf)
- /camera_base_link3->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link2->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera/depth_registered/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/rgb/debayer->/rosout (/rosout)

How to connect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39817/kinect-communication-problem/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it can be fixed by installing openjdk 7. http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.ca/2012/05/install-openjdk-7-in-xubuntu-1204.html

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0